# Is Kotlin Poet JVM target only? I want to use it for native

Tags: kotlin, kotlinpoet

Did not find any reference on that - all examples seem to be using KVM / Android code. Is it possible to use Poet for a native target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KotlinPoet itself is built against Kotlin JVM and references JDK code, so you'll need Java to run it, however you can use KotlinPoet to generate platform-agnostic Kotlin code.

Comment: This explains a number of things, thanks!